# Powershell env:dir variables

Tags: variables, powershell

I'm using powershell 4 when I run `$env:logonserver` I don't get any results, when I use the same command in powershell 3 it works great.  On my box with powershell 4 when I use cmd and run `%logonserver%` I get the result I'm looking for.

My question is does anyone know how to bring `$env:logonserver` back or another method to get the same result?  I use this command as part of my logon script.

Comment: Are you runing PowerShell under your own account, or did you right click and select `run as`?  If the latter, PowerShell's running as a different user, and that user may not have this environment variable.  Run `$env:username` to check which user your PS session is running under.

Answer (score 2):

```
$env:logonserver
```

Works for me on my V4 system, as does

```
cmd /c "echo %logonserver%"
```

Comment: Works for me as well on V4.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was running my powershell session using the "Run as different user" option, since that account was not logged into anything I was not showing results for $env:logonserver.

Answer (score -1):

Try the below query, I hope it works.

```
Get-Content env:logonserver  "Results will be out"
```

Comment: rewrite your post to remove fluff, and format code with four spaces before, or surround with ```